# Stacktrace in Eclipse console not clickable / no hyperlinks

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse project with Spring Boot that is started via Gradle Launch configuration. Although workspace is set correctly on project that contains the Gradle build as well as the sources under src/main/java below the Gradle build file the stacktraces in the normal console log are not clickable. What prerequisites am I missing?